# Заполнить переменную только при первом вызове функции postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть функция, возвращающая таблицу. При вызове функции создается переменная-массив, которую необходимо заполнить случайными числами. Затем возвращается таблица с числами из переменной. Так вот, как сделать так, чтобы заполнение происходило только при первом обращении к функции? При последующих должны возвращаться те же самые значения, а не каждый раз генерироваться новые.

```html
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fnc_generate_goods()
RETURNS TABLE (good VARCHAR, price INT) AS $$
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..20 LOOP
        RETURN QUERY(SELECT ('товар' || to_char(i, 'FM00'))::VARCHAR, i);
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Хочу рандомно сгенерировать цену для товаров, но чтобы она не менялась каждый раз при обращении к этой функции. Конечно, это можно сделать просто создав новую таблицу, но по заданию так нельзя...

Comment: А у вас в задании сказано что цена должна быть рандомной. И на проверку каких знаний это задание ? Что до вашего вопроса, то не сохраняя явно сгенеренную последовательность куда нибудь в базу это, на сколько я знаю, невозможно

Comment: @Mike возможно, если инициализировать генератор случайных чисел перед генерацией цен

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov Ну я говорил что невозможно сохранить значение, не записывая. хотел предложить какой нибудь кастомный генератор чисел, в зависимости от реальной задачи, если автор ответит. А вот то что можно встроенному рандому сид указать не знал

Answer (score 1):

Если инициализировать random каждый раз одни и тем же числом, то цены будут случайные, но воспроизводимые между вызовами, если передавать seed в параметрах (захардкодить в функции тоже можно).

<s>**Но этот подход имеет серьёзный недостаток - все вызовы random() после вызова этой функции тоже будут воспроизводиться, поэтому использовать стоит только для учебных заданий или в сценариях тестирования.**</s>  Добавил восстановление случайной последовательности.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fnc_generate_goods(price_seed float)
    RETURNS TABLE (good VARCHAR, price INT) AS $$
declare
    previous_seed float;    
BEGIN
    select random() into previous_seed; -- remember current sequence
    
    perform setseed(price_seed); -- generate expected sequence
    
    FOR i IN 1..5 LOOP
            RETURN QUERY(SELECT ('товар' || to_char(i, 'FM00'))::VARCHAR, (random()*1000)::int);
        END LOOP;

    perform setseed(previous_seed*2 - 1.0); -- restore sequence
    
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Ниже вызовы `fnc_generate_goods(0.43)` и `fnc_generate_goods(0.44)` генерируют воспроизводимые цены, при этом вызовы `random()` за пределами `fnc_generate_goods` продолжают давать случайные числа.

```
postgres=# select * from fnc_generate_goods(0.43);
  good   | price 
---------+-------
 B>20@01 |   155
 B>20@02 |    16
 B>20@03 |   853
 B>20@04 |   745
 B>20@05 |   753
(5 rows)

postgres=# select random();
       random       
--------------------
 0.4382084077869095
(1 row)

postgres=# select * from fnc_generate_goods(0.44);
  good   | price 
---------+-------
 B>20@01 |   740
 B>20@02 |   736
 B>20@03 |   845
 B>20@04 |   614
 B>20@05 |   977
(5 rows)

postgres=# select random();
      random       
-------------------
 0.918940566300332
(1 row)

postgres=# select * from fnc_generate_goods(0.43);
  good   | price 
---------+-------
 B>20@01 |   155
 B>20@02 |    16
 B>20@03 |   853
 B>20@04 |   745
 B>20@05 |   753
(5 rows)

postgres=# select random();
       random       
--------------------
 0.7218863495340173
(1 row)

postgres=# select * from fnc_generate_goods(0.44);
  good   | price 
---------+-------
 B>20@01 |   740
 B>20@02 |   736
 B>20@03 |   845
 B>20@04 |   614
 B>20@05 |   977
(5 rows)

postgres=# select random();
       random       
--------------------
 0.5467171552940719
(1 row)
```